# Modification of Data Frame based on Group By in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data Frame with Following Columns: *Folder_Number*, *File_Name*, *Val_Indices* and *Final_Result*.
*Val_Indices* and *Final_Result* can take values: 0, 1 or 2

Sample Data

```
+---------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| Folder_Number | File_Name | Val_Indices | Final_Result |
+===============+===========+=============+==============+
|      100      | ABC.png   |      0      |       1      |
+---------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|      100      | DEF.png   |      0      |       0      |
+---------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|      100      | EFG.png   |      0      |       1      |
+---------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|      200      | HIJ.png   |      1      |       0      |
+---------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|      200      | KLM.png   |      1      |       1      |
+---------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|      300      | NOP.png   |      2      |       2      |
+---------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

I want Data to be Grouped by *Folder_Number*, and *Final_Result* value for all rows corresponding to that *Folder_Number* should be min of the value in that group.

For Example, corresponding to `Folder_Number = 100`, I want all rows of folder number 100 to have `Final_Result = 0` (Minimum of 1, 0, 1).

Similarly, corresponding to folder number 200, all rows should have `Final_Result = 0` (Minimum of 0 and 1).

Corresponding to folder number 300, all rows should have `Final_Result = 2` (Folder 300 has only 1 `Final_Result` value)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
df['Final_Result'] = df.groupby('Folder_Number')['Val_Indices'].transform(min)
```